Question from 2017 SACE Math Methods Exam
This question comes from the 2017 SACE Mathematical Methods final exam booklet 2. It is Question 12 c (v).
"The distributer of a particular seed claims that, on average, 60% of the seeds are viable, meaning that they will grow into seedlings." So from the questions prior to my issue I have found:
$$X\sim B(8,0.6)$$
$$E(X)=4.8$$
Part c begins with "A farmer bought a bag of these seeds. She plated 100 of the seeds from this bag and observed that 53 of these seeds were viable". From here:
$$\hat{p}=0.53$$
And the 95% confidence interval for the proportion of seeds in the bag that are viable is:
$$0.432 \leqslant \hat{p} \leqslant 0.628$$
The question which I am having an issue with is as follows:
"The farmer wishes to reduce the uncertainty in the estimate of the proportion of seeds in her bag that are viable. Calculate the smallest number of seeds that shee would need to plant in order to have a confidence interval width 0.1." A hint is given to consider that: Given an estimate $p^*$, the sample size $n$ required to obtain a 95% confidence interval of width $w$ for the population proportion is:
$$n=\left(\frac{2 \times 1.96}{w}\right)^2 p^*\left(1-p^*\right)$$
According to the answer, they use $p^*=0.5$, however I am not sure where this result is coming from.
I currently have no idea on how to approach the problem, primarily the value of $p^*$. Any help is appreciated!

It is probably safe to assume $p^*=0.53$ as this was the initial point estimate for $p$.

$p=\frac12$ maximises $p(1-p)$ so can be treated as the worst case in calculating the standard error of $p^*$
